# Javascript code to conditionally disable radio button based on select input works on pc browser, but non on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, disabled-input

Basically the script does its work on chrome/firefox for pc, enabling and disabling the optionalBtn when in need, while it remains disabled on chrome/firefox for mobile.

At first I thought I had misplaced the script in the body, instead it doesn't work in the head yet.
I read about cache problems relative to js on android but didn't find anything at all.

I'm starting to suspect it is a matter derived by the 'onclick' event, because in mobile browsers the website shows a modal from the select that I believe it is not as visiting a web page from chrome on windows.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
</head> 
<body>

    <form method="post" action="transaction.php">

        <select name="conditionSelec" required>
            <option id="disableMyBtn" value="value1">disable my btn</option>
            <option class="enableMyBtn" value="value2">1...enable my btn 1</option>
            <!-- more options -->
            <option class="enableMyBtn" value="valueN">2...enable my btn N</option>
        </select>

        <br><br>

        <label><input class="checkButton" type="radio" name="checkButtons" value="value1" checked>Always enabled btn</label>
        <br>
        <label><input class="checkButton" type="radio" name="checkButtons" value="value2" id="optionalBtn">Conditionally enabled btn</label>

        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit">

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var enableMyBtnArray = document.getElementsByClassName('enableMyBtn');
        var optionalBtnVar = document.getElementById('optionalBtn');

        optionalBtnVar.disabled = true;

        document.getElementById('disableMyBtn').onclick = function() {
            optionalBtnVar.disabled = true;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < enableMyBtnArray.length; i++) {
            enableMyBtnArray[i].onclick = function() {
                optionalBtnVar.disabled = false;
            }
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `option` elements on mobile devices don't have normal behavior for `click` so that actions like scrolling can be handled correctly.  Some browsers (chrome/safari?) may not even fire a `click` for options.  You might want to re-think your design

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you point me to any direction I could take?

Comment: I wrote a script that first makes use of `document.querySelector`to get the select, then the method `onchange` on the select itself to listen for events. Finally I disabled the radio button based on the `selectedIndex`. Thank you @Tibrogargan because you made me do the right researches.